# Django run admin inteface with custom template

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates

In django how to run /admin interface as well as customized admin index page. My template dirs is followed below.

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/templates/',
)

And...

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '//admin/'

If i will comment this line my other functions would not work, if i put it uncommented then ma admin interface shows my specified file.

What should i do to run both simultaneously. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Leave `TEMPLATE_DIRS` alone, that affects more than just the admin, and that's not your problem anyways.

The way to override any admin page is to include the associated template from the default Django admin templates in your own 'yourproject/templates/admin' directory, and make the necessary modifications.

See the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates